# How to enforce RVO for operator return value?

Tags: c++, rvo, nrvo

How to enforce RVO in the last 3 operators:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Noisy {
    private:
        int m_value;
    public:
        Noisy(int value = 0): m_value(value) 
        {
            std::cout << "Noisy(int)\n";
        }
        Noisy(const Noisy& other): m_value(other.m_value)  
        { 
            std::cout << "Noisy(const Noisy&)\n";
        }
        Noisy(Noisy&& other): m_value(other.m_value)
        { 
            std::cout << "Noisy(Noisy&&)\n";
        }
        //~Noisy() {
        //    std::cout << "dtor\n";
        //}
        Noisy operator+(const Noisy& rhs) &
        {
            std::cout << "+(const Noisy&)&\n";
            return Noisy(m_value + rhs.m_value);
        }
        Noisy operator+(Noisy&& rhs) &
        {
            std::cout << "+(Noisy&&)&\n";
            rhs.m_value += m_value;
            return rhs; //std::move(rhs);
        }
        Noisy operator+(const Noisy& rhs) &&
        {
            std::cout << "+(const Noisy&) &&\n";
            this->m_value += rhs.m_value;
            return *this; //std::move(*this);
        }

        Noisy operator+(Noisy&& rhs) &&
        {
            std::cout << "+(Noisy&&) &&\n";
            this->m_value += rhs.m_value;
            return *this; //std::move(*this);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Noisy a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    Noisy z = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;

    return 0;
}
```

The program run output:

```
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
+(const Noisy&)&
Noisy(int)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(const Noisy&)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(const Noisy&)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(const Noisy&)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(const Noisy&)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(const Noisy&)
```

or when explicitly using `std::move` in the last three operators:

```
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
+(const Noisy&)&
Noisy(int)
+(const Noisy&) && 
Noisy(Noisy&&)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(Noisy&&)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(Noisy&&)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(Noisy&&)
+(const Noisy&) &&
Noisy(Noisy&&)
```

I want no copying in the operators, something like this:

```
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
Noisy(int)
+(const Noisy&)&
Noisy(int)
+(const Noisy&) &&
+(const Noisy&) &&
+(const Noisy&) &&
+(const Noisy&) &&
+(const Noisy&) &&
```

The only way i figured so far is to return a reference from the operators but this clearly would result in a dangling reference.

I compile in c++14 and c++17 with fresh g++.

**Update**

I understood that it is not possible to force the compiler to do what i want without breaking rules.
But what ptevents the compiler to optimize rvalues locally?
I imagine it can create a single rvalue during the first addition which is modified in the next additions and then assigned to the result variable.

Comment: Your last 3 operators return a copy. You cannot do RVO here, because that would modify `this`.

Comment: @user207421 `operator+` should return a new value. But it should not modify the operands. So it is wrong, but for different reasons.

Comment: @juanchopanza why it should return a new value if there is a rvalue reference that can be modified and returned?

Comment: @AndreyGodyaev Those are the expected semantics of binary `operator+`. You pass two things, you get another thing back. Modifying either operand would just be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Make your rvalue-reference-caller + const-reference argument operator return an rvalue-reference that is `std::move`ed out of `*this`.

```
Noisy&& operator+(const Noisy& rhs) &&
{
    std::cout << "+(const Noisy&)&&\n";
    m_value += rhs.m_value;
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

Since this is being fired from an rvalue-reference, you can freely abuse, and move, `*this` down to the caller where they are free to do whatever they please with it.

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>

class Noisy {
private:
    int m_value;
public:
    Noisy(int value = 0) : m_value(value)
    {
        std::cout << "Noisy()\n";
    }
    Noisy(const Noisy& other) : m_value(other.m_value)
    {
        std::cout << "Noisy(const Noisy&)\n";
    }
    Noisy(Noisy&& other) : m_value(other.m_value)
    {
        std::cout << "Noisy(Noisy&&)\n";
        other.m_value = -1;
    }

    ~Noisy()
    {
        std::cout << "~Noisy() : " << m_value << '\n';
    }

    Noisy operator+(const Noisy& rhs) const &
    {
        std::cout << "+(const Noisy&)&\n";
        return Noisy(m_value + rhs.m_value);
    }

    Noisy&& operator+(const Noisy& rhs) &&
    {
        std::cout << "+(const Noisy&)&&\n";
        m_value += rhs.m_value;
        return std::move(*this);
    }

    Noisy operator+(Noisy&& rhs) const
    {
        std::cout << "+(Noisy&&)\n";
        rhs.m_value += m_value;
        return std::move(rhs);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Noisy a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    std::cout << "========================\n";

    Noisy z = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
    std::cout << "========================\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Noisy()
Noisy()
Noisy()
Noisy()
Noisy()
Noisy()
Noisy()
========================
+(const Noisy&)&
Noisy()
+(const Noisy&)&&
+(const Noisy&)&&
+(const Noisy&)&&
+(const Noisy&)&&
+(const Noisy&)&&
Noisy(Noisy&&)
~Noisy() : -1
========================
~Noisy() : 0
~Noisy() : 0
~Noisy() : 0
~Noisy() : 0
~Noisy() : 0
~Noisy() : 0
~Noisy() : 0
~Noisy() : 0
```

Notice after the initial construction of `a.operator+(b)`, the resulting object is propagated by rvalue-reference down the chain. The last operation is the move-construction into `z`. (thus the `-1` in the destructor report).

---

I had prepared a long description of how your operator chaining makes this work that I was going to post, but in the end it got rather cluttered. Suffice it to say that this:

```
Noisy z = a.operator+(b).operator+(c).operator+(....
```

is what you're doing, and you need to get the lhs operand of everything past `(b)` in the chain to push its rvalue-reference to the next call. The operator I showed will allow that.

Best of luck, I hope I understood your goal.

Comment: Is  `Noisy&& x = Noisy(1) + Noisy(1);` safe with your version of the operator? I think it is a dangling reference.

Comment: @AndreyGodyaev I just saw the expression in your question. I thought you were asking about the example I posted. The code line you present wouldn't even compile with the operators in my example due to ambiguity in two different `operator +` implementation (the one offered, and `Noisy operator+(Noisy&& rhs)` ). Are you asking whether an rvalue-reference lifetime extension would work with that operator ? I don't think it will, so if that's critical, this isn't going to work.

Comment: So if I want safe universal code i'm stuck with the operators that returns `Noisy`. I still have a question: what prevents the compiler from removing redundant copying during optimisation?

Comment: @AndreyGodyaev: The fact that you put a bunch of printing statements in your copy constructors. Copies are not "redundant"; they're required by the standard. The compiler can only remove them if it *knows for certain* that the visible behavior of your code would be unchanged. If you `= default` these constructors and operators, then the compiler can eliminate them where it sees fit.

Comment: @NicolBolas I saw what happens in the assembly with and without std::cout. The compiler is smart.